# Too many redirections on res.render in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization

I try to redirect my frontpage's `/` route to the query parameter string from i18n middleware, because I'm translating my site:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/' + req.getLocale());
});
app.use('/:lang', index);
```

So I'm expecting to be redirected from `/` to `/hu`.

I'm using i18n-node middleware plugin. The needed part from the documentation is here: https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node#i18ngetlocale

However this is causing way too many redirects and the site not loads with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. This is the console output:

```
GET / 302 18.685 ms - 50
GET /hu 302 4.789 ms - 50
GET /hu 302 3.312 ms - 50
GET /hu 302 4.679 ms - 50
GET /hu 302 2.234 ms - 50
GET /hu 302 4.708 ms - 50
GET /hu 302 3.040 ms - 50
...
```

What causing this?

**EDIT**

This is my index router:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  fsAsync(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render('404', {
        titleShown: true,
        title: 'Error 404',
        description: 'Error 404',
        keywords: 'error,404'
      });
    }

    var gallery = data[0].gallery.portfolio.love;
    //var json = gallery;
    //console.log(json);

    var articles = data[1].articles.reverse();
    var slice = articles.slice(0, 6);
    var json = [{ articles: slice }];

    res.render('index', {
      //layout: 'main',
      titleShown: false,
      title: 'Hi!',
      description: 'Home page',
      keywords: 'wedding,photography,film,lantos,istvan',
      data: gallery,
      latestPosts: json
    });
  });
});
```

If anyone wants to take a deep look, here is my app.js: https://github.com/DJviolin/lantosistvan/blob/3573390386ea4fe5b7f418b3fbaa118673b6b6d6/app.js

**SOLUTION**

Just change up the route order, because where I wanted to redirect didn't existed yet:

```
app.use('/:lang', index);
app.use('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/' + req.getLocale());
});
```

**Update**

Someone can explain to me how my question is the duplicate if I posted this 4 months earlier than the other?

Comment: What does your `index` look like?

Comment: Question updated with the index router.

Comment: And you've tried switching the order of those two `app.use` lines?

Comment: No, but now I tried and it solved! Thank You! I thought first I'm redirecting to the route but looks like it didn't existed where I wanted to redirect. My bad. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS making repeat redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130104/nodejs-making-repeat-redirects)