# NodeJS making repeat redirects

Tags: node.js, redirect

I am in the process of moving from PHP to NodeJS, I'm trying to understand why a middleware redirect is spinning out of control.

```
// Check to see if the request includes a session Username
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  sessionmanager = req.session;
  if(sessionmanager.Username) {
    console.log('Session Details detected');
    next();
  } else {
    console.log('No session details detected, pushing user to login page');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});

// User Landing Page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for landing page');
  res.send('Welcome Page!');
});


// User Login Page
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for User login page');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'login.html'));
});
```

When I visit localhost:3000 it redirects me to localhost:3000/login but the page fails to load because it looks like its been redirected too many times. 
When I look at the console log, I can count; 20+ rows of message 'No session details detected, pushing user to login page'.

From what I can guess, the redirect loops back to app.use function, fails to pass the session manager.Username statement and gets stuck in a loop. 
Whats the best way to redirect traffic to the /login page? Can I put an exclude clause in app.use?

Answer (score 1):

From reading the docs at: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
You can set the requests so that /login comes before app.use this way its not part of the redirect loop. 
Example:

```
// User Login Page
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for User login page');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'login.html'));
});

// Check to see if the request includes a session Username
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  sessionmanager = req.session;
  if(sessionmanager.Username) {
    console.log('Session Details detected');
    next();
  } else {
    console.log('No session details detected, pushing user to login page');
    res.redirect('/login');
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'login.html'));
  }
});

// User Landing Page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for landing page');
  res.send('Welcome Page!');
});
```

Now you can make requests to the /login url and any pages past app.use will push you back to the login page if you have not got a session logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You have your login route below the middleware. It should be to top of your route list something like this

```
// User Login Page
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for User login page');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'login.html'));
});

// Check to see if the request includes a session Username
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  sessionmanager = req.session;
  if(sessionmanager.Username) {
    console.log('Session Details detected');
    next();
  } else {
    console.log('No session details detected, pushing user to login page');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});

// User Landing Page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Request for landing page');
  res.send('Welcome Page!');
});
```

- Middleware will execute for all the routes below you mentioned.
- In your code you are redirecting to /login if session is not set
- Will again check middleware before /login results in redirect loop

Hope you understand